# Let $W \subset V$ vector spaces, let $W'$ be the orthogonal complement of $W$. Show $\dim(W)+\dim(W')=\dim V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

As title says:
Let $W \subset V$ vector spaces, let $W'$ be the orthogonal complement of $W$. Show $\dim(W)+\dim(W')=\dim V$.

We are given that $W \subset V$ **finite** vector spaces, symmetric bilinear mapping $B: V\times V \to \mathbb R$, $Q$ is the quadratic form that corresponds to $B$ (meaning $Q(x)=B(x,x)$)

$W'=\{u\in V| B(u,x)=0 \forall x \in W\}$

We are given also that $Q$ is nondegenerate (meaning, it has no zero eigenvalue. the number of positive eigenvalues+the number of negative eigenvalues = dimV)

Show that $\dim W+\dim W'=\dim V$

I nearly got the solution, just need one last push

**What I did:**

I wanted to show that $V$ is a direct sum of $W$ and $W'$:

Lemma: if Q is nondegenerate then $Q(x)=0$ implies $x=0$

proof: Q is nondegenerate so there is no $0$ eigenvalue, so the only vector that $Q$ sends to $0$ has to be the $0$ vector.

let $x \in W\cap W'$, then $B(x \in W',x \in W)=B(x,x)=0$ which means $Q(x)=0$, from the lemma, it follows that $x=0$. So it is indeed a direct sum.

Now we need to prove that $V\subseteq W\cup W'$ and $W\cup W' \subseteq V$:

**$W\cup W' \subseteq V$**:

let $x\in W\cup W'$, if $x\in W$ then $x \in V$ because $W \subset V$. If $x\in W'$ then for the same reason $x \in V$, because $W' \subset V$.

Now we just need to show that $V\subseteq W\cup W'$:

let $x \in V$. if $x \in W$ then it is trivial. So assume $x \in V$ and $x \notin W$

**Why is $x\in W'$ in that case?**

Comment: Note that $W \cup W'$ need not be a vector space. You probably mean $W + W'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By nondegeneracy and symmetry, $B(\cdot,\cdot)$ is an inner product on $V$. Let ${x_1, \ldots, x_m}$ be a basis for $W$. After modification by the Gram-Schmidt process, if necessary, you can assume that the basis is orthogonal with respect to $B(\cdot, \cdot)$, that is $B(x_i, x_j) = 0$ when $i \neq j$. Now complete the basis such that ${x_1, \ldots, x_m, y_1, \ldots, y_n}$ is a basis for $V$. Again, let's say it is orthogonal with respect to $B(\cdot,\cdot)$. Of course, $m + n = \mathrm{dim}V$. Moreover, you can check that $W'$ is the span of the $y_i$'s. So $\mathrm{dim}W = m$ and $\mathrm{dim}W' = n$.

I hope this provides some intuition at least, if not the expected answer.

Comment: Could you explain why it is an inner product? I thought its an inner product only if it's definite positive. But otherwise, this is a very well thought argument. I'd just like to know why it's an inner product, and why my argument fails.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is not necessarily positive definite, and therefore not an inner product. One could fix this by flipping the eigenvalues (and consider a $\tilde{B}$), but I think this is a cumbersome solution and there is a more elegant way.