# can someone explain a part of this short proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/775640/416562

after he said that $\forall i=k+1,..,n$ the $u_i$ are in $W^{\perp}$ how did he conclude that ${u_{k+1},...,u_n}$ is a basis of $W^{\perp}$ ?

Comment: Gram Schmidt process preserves span. You can try to prove that $u_{k+1},...,u_n$ is indeed a basis for $W^\perp$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear that $u_{k+1}, \dots, u_n$ are linearly independent, so all we need to prove now is that they span the set $W^\bot$.

Take any $x\in W^\bot$. Then, we also know that $x\in V$.

Now, because $u_1, \dots u_n$ form a basis for $V$, we can write $$x=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i u_i$$

However, we also know that $$\langle x, u_i\rangle = \alpha_i$$ because $u_i$ are all orthonormal.

> In case you aren't sure: $$\langle x, u_i\rangle = \left\langle \sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j u_j, u_i\right\rangle \\
> = \sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j\left\langle u_j, u_i\right\rangle = \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\alpha_j\left\langle u_j, u_i\right\rangle + \alpha_i\langle u_i,u_i\rangle\sum_{j=i+1}^n\alpha_j\left\langle u_j, u_i\right\rangle\\=0+\alpha_i+0$$

This means that $\alpha_i=0$ for $i\leq k$, which means that $$x=\sum_{i=k+1}^n\alpha_i u_i$$
which proves that $x$ is in the span of $u_{k+1}, \dots, u_n$